# Diophantine equation $11\cdot 2^y-3x^{10}=2014$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Ok so I have a trouble figure out here

For the Diophantine equation $11\cdot 2^y-3x^{10}=2014$, either find all integer solutions, or show that there are no integer solutions.

Comment: What is $x^{10}$ modulo $11$ ?

Comment: 87 I believe, Is it related to this question?

Comment: thats a Fermatt's little theorem, and it's equal to 1

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Work with respect to modulo 11. Then the LHS is either -3 or 0, while the RHS is 1. So there are no integer solutions to this equation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, a typo, but a costly one ;)

Comment: So I assume i start 11*2^y=11    and -3x-2014=11 ?? Thank you for ur respond

Comment: @user116227 Note that no matter what value for $y$ we have that $11\cdot 2^y$ is divisible by 11. So we need to have:

$$2014 + 3x^{10} \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$$

If $x$ is divisible by 11, then also $3x^{10}$ is divisible, so the LHS is divisible by 11, while the RHS isn't. Contradiction.

If $x$ is coprime to 11, then from Fermat's Little Therorem we have:

$$2014 + 3x^{10} \equiv 1 + 3\cdot1 \equiv 4 \not\equiv 0 \pmod {11}$$